# Unexpected error while parsing JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting a string object after splitting from a text. Now I am trying to convert that text to a JSON object.

**Text after Splitting**

```
{location:"Web",initial:"",firmType:"",toaxfrtype:""}
```

When I am trying to parse it using **JSON.parse**, I am getting an error,

SyntaxError: Unexpected token l.

I have some other string value as the same in the above text. It was parsing fine using JSON.parse. Only the above string is not working.
Can anybody help me in this issue.

Comment: Its already a object. So what do you want to achieve using `JSON.parse`?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Example

Answer (score 3):

You need quotes `"` so change

```
 {location:"Web",initial:"",firmType:"",toaxfrtype:""}
```

to

```
 {"location":"Web","initial":"","firmType":"","toaxfrtype":""}
```

I have attached the image where it says valid now after correction. You can online validators to validate it first.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not JSON. You need to quote all Strings, including the keys.